# 'first_time_accessed' Shopify liquid variable is always false

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to use the `first_time_accessed` liquid variable in my `checkout.liquid` Shopify template to decide whether or not to push certain data to an array, like so:

```
  config.elements.push({
    id: prodId,
    price: prodPrice,
    quantity: prodQty,
    {% if first_time_accessed %}
      {% assign last_purchase_date = "January 1, 1970" %}
      {% for order in customer.orders %}
        {% if (order.order_number != checkout.order.order_number) and (order.created_at > last_purchase_date) %}
          {% assign last_purchase_date = order.created_at %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% assign raw_new_customer_boundary = 'now' | date: "%s" | minus : 46656000 /* 540 days */ %}
      {% assign raw_last_purchase_date = last_purchase_date | date: "%s" | minus: 0 %}
      new_customer: {% if raw_new_customer_boundary > raw_last_purchase_date %}true{% else %}false{% endif %},
    {% endif %}
  });
```

However, every time I test this code I can see that `first_time_accessed` is always false. I've also tested this by putting similar code on other pages and it always equates to false. I've tested it in incognito mode with a VPN and same thing.

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea why `first_time_accessed` is always false? I'm sure it has to do with some misunderstanding on my end about how this variable works, but there's very little info on Shopify's docs about it.

Comment: I can be wrong but isn't `first_time_accessed` is only available in the additional_scripts textarea in Shopify?

Comment: @drip I'm afraid you're probably right. All the documentation I can find only discusses using `first_time_accessed` within the context of additonal_scripts. I just thought there must be some way to use it in my custom template code, as every other liquid variable seems to be available in this way.

Comment: drip is correct, `first_time_accessed` is only functional in the extra scripts section of the settings.